# How to make a npm stop that terminates the correct forever

Tags: node.js, npm, forever

I am using forever in npm start to start the node.js app, and I would like to have a npm stop to terminate the task. How can I stop the right task? I really like to not use stop all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you want to assing a `uid` and then stop the process based on assign name, for example:
1. Starting:
`forever start --uid=myapp index.js`
2. Stopping only `myapp`:
`forever stop myapp`